# React Native + Redux + HMR + connect

Tags: react-native, redux, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

I'm trying to get stuff working but I can't success.
Initially I get the following error :

```
<Provider> does not support changing `store` on the fly. It is most likely that you see this error because you updated to Redux 2.x and React Redux 2.x which no longer hot reload reducers automatically.
    See https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v2.0.0 for the migration instructions.
```

I followed instructions on the page, it was hard to understand that I had to put the store creation in the `index.android.js` and pass it as a prop, where the **HMR** does not rerender stuff so the store is not created again. But I finally get rid of the error.

I can now see that my store is update in the `module.hot.accept` function in the `App/Redux/createStore` function when I change any reducer, the `App/Redux/SearchRedux` initial state for exemple.

But my application state is not refreshed at all if I edit a reducer ! Even worst, when I do that the whole app gets disconnected from the state (but I havn't exemple on this simpler app so lets focus on the state not getting reinjected).
I can see it in `App/Navigation/ReduxNavigation`

You can reproduce the bug easily by cloning [the repo](https://github.com/l1br3/ReactNative-Redux-HMR-Broken).

I struggle on this one since this morning, time starts to be long so I finally post on SO. I've read a lot of stuff related to this issue but its obvious I'm missing something.

PS: Initially I wrote this with many links to the files so you can directly see what I mean with code. But I have few reputation despite I use the site for few years (because I always found answers, not this time)
You will find this question with the links in the repo readme, it will be easier to see files I'm talking about.

Thanks

Comment: DONE ! A simple misconfiguration. It's very hard to understand how to configure it but it's done. Solution in the repo.